# Sending attachments

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm having some trouble sending a picture to the user.
What I did, was follow [Bot Docs Attachments](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html#imagefileattachments) and copied the code. The variable "replyMessage" for me is what is at [Bot Docs Activities](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#replytoactivity) (which is`incomingMessage.CreateReply("Yo, I heard you.", "en");`). So, I'm having troubles sending that image/attachment. I used the `await` and `ReplyToActivityAsync` and `replyMessage` as it is explained in that link. Can someone please explain how attachments and activities work and find a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's going wrong without seeing the actual code you are using; however if you want to know how to send attachments I recommend you to check the [SendAttachment](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-SendAttachment) sample of the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repository.

In the sample you will find the code ready to be executed and tested in the emulator and also a brief explanation about how attachments works.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that activity.Attachments is not initialized as a List and it is not mentioned anywhere in the docs that you have to do

```
activity.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
```

before you add the attachments to the activity. I also tried copying the official code samples and it turns out that was the reason why they didn't work.

Comment: I tried using `List<Attachment>();` before, but I got an error message saying _The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

Comment: You need to add "using System.Collections.Generic;" . Check the sample I shared earlier :)